# Is it appropriate to say directly "x belongs to y (a category)"?

Tags: grammar

You belong to the cleverest human being. (self-made)

Is this clear enough, or should I say: You belong to the category of the cleverest human being.

Comment: *"Tiddles, you belong to the fattest cat." *"Tiddles, you belong to the category of the fattest cat." "Tiddles, you belong in the 'fattest cat' category." (But ELL is the correct forum for this sort of question.)

Comment: Tiddles was a victim of his own fame. Tiddles *defined* the fattest cat category.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with the sentence "You belong to the cleverest human being".

First, "belong to" is ambiguous - it can mean "be a member of" or "be owned by".  Without context, it's impossible to tell which was meant.

Second, "the cleverest human being" is a category containing only one person.  It is not a group you can be a member of.

So the most natural reading of "You belong to the cleverest human being" would be "You are owned by the cleverest human being".

---

"You belong to the category of the cleverest human being" is less ambiguous, but very long-winded.  It's a rather roundabout way of saying "You are the cleverest human being".